What’s the shortest judgment by UK Supreme Court, or Appellate Committee of the House of Lords?
Disregard the Judicial Committee of Privy Council in this question. Although he's British, Lord Justice Haddon-Cave weirdly cited the shortest American - but not British - judgment in “English Law and Descent into Complexity”, Lord Justice Haddon-Cave’s Gray’s Inn Reading on 17th June 2021.


The shortest judgment ever written was probably Chief Justice John Marshall’s six word opinion in United States v. Barker (1817) which read simply “The Supreme Court never
pays costs”.60 There is no arguing with the simplicity of that!


Footnote 60 cites United States v. Barker 15 U.S. (2 Wheat.) 395 (1817).

There are probably lots of trivial cases that contain no substantive legal reasoning: "dismissed for lack of jurisdiction", "dismissed for failure to pay fees", "affirmed per curium", "review denied", "dismissed as moot", "affirmed for lack of quorum".

@ohwilleke please reword, and improve, my question for me? Unquestionably, I'm referring to judgments with a tad of substantive legal reasoning.

I wouldn't know where to draw the line.

The actual judgement is “The United States never pays costs”.

Practice in the House of Lords, and the Supreme Court, has each judge giving their own separate opinion. Today there is some pressure against having short concurring opinions, and most cases are delivered as a single-authored judgment, with which the other justices agree without having to make a speech about it. But in many prior cases there will be opinions like "I agree with Lord Smith", or "I concur" which are certainly short, although probably not what this question is getting at.
In earlier times, judgments would often have been given ex tempore, that is by the judge speaking out loud what he thought, instead of delivering a pre-prepared document. These would tend to be shorter than today's judgments which often set out large tracts of legislation and case law verbatim. In many instances, the judgment would just say the decision that was made, without giving a reason. An example chosen at random: Jeffrey v Ure and Miller (1825) 1 W&S 565, wherein

The House of Lords ordered and adjudged that the interlocutors complained of be reversed, and that the defender be assoilzied.

without any more rationale being recorded. Let us also discount this sort of thing and say that we are interested in an actual substantive reasoned judgment also being short.
In the modern era, probably the shortest substantive leading judgment is from Lord Wilberforce in Brumby (Inspector of Taxes) v Miller [1976] UKHL 7. This was a tax appeal, which normally result in long and detailed dissections of the law. However, Lord Wilberforce took just five paragraphs to deal with this one; three to explain the factual background to the dispute, and the remaining two to say:

The taxability of the annual distributions under the scheme is not an issue
in this appeal but nobody has suggested, or could suggest that these were
not taxable. The only question is whether any ground could be found for
distinguishing the capital payments made on the winding up of the scheme.
In my opinion, with all respect to the efforts of learned counsel for the
taxpayer, there is no ground for any such distinction. I shall not attempt to
demonstrate this by detailed analysis of the Trust Deed, or by reference to
such authorities as may, possibly, be relevant, since this has been done to
my complete satisfaction by the Court of Appeal, affirming Walton J. To
restate the argument in words of my own, even if this were to result in a
difference of formulation, would not be productive of advantage, and I am
more than content fully to adopt the single judgment of the Court of Appeal
delivered by Lord Russell of Killowen.
The appeal can only be dismissed.

The other law lords concurred, some at roughly the same length, but with Lord Diplock's entire contribution being the words "My Lords, I agree". The entire set of judgments only takes up a few pages in the printed reports.

9 words
It’s a Court of Chancellory judgement from before the unification of the law and chancellory courts. Lillicott v Compton 1708 judge unknown:

Plate shall pass by a devise of household goods.

Which I believe is still good law.

I did not downvote this but the Court of Chancery was a different court from the UKHL/UKSC

I found a precise reference btw: Lillcott v Compton (1708) 2 Vern 638. Also in Equity Cases Abridged 200, pl.5

But Court of Chancery wasn't UKHL/UKSC?

No, but it was the one of the highest courts at the time.
